# android tv remote control key listen

Tags: android, listener, television

I will try to capture remote control keys on app on android TV, I implemented keydown method like this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode == 10010){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Button X pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        pulsarBotonTV();
        return true;
    }
    //....
    else{
     Toast.makeText(this, "ANOTHER KEY"+keyCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.w("app", "Keycode else: " + keyCode);
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

}

I can capture the most keys but, I can´t capture shortcut keys.
TV, FILE,WEB,SET ( image:[image of shortcuts keys][1] )

So, on standard key press on remote control, I can capture key and see on logcat:

---

D/WindowManager(1943): mBootFastRuning = false shutdhownPending = false

D/InputManager-JNI(1943): handleInterceptActions: POLICY_FLAG_PASS_TO_USER.

D/WindowManager(1943): isFactoryConfigExist retval = false

D/WindowManager(1943): keycode is 8 , and POWER is 26

D/LatinIME(2370): key event KEYCODE_1

**W/app(25843): Keycode por else: 8**

D/WindowManager(1943): mBootFastRuning = false shutdhownPending = false

D/InputManager-JNI(1943): handleInterceptActions: POLICY_FLAG_PASS_TO_USER.

D/WindowManager(1943): isFactoryConfigExist retval = false

D/WindowManager(1943): keycode is 8 , and POWER is 26

**W/app(25843): Keycode por else: 8**

---

but when press shortcut keys no keydown method is called, I can see on logcat:

---

D/WindowManager(1943): mBootFastRuning = false shutdhownPending = false

D/InputManager-JNI(1943): handleInterceptActions: POLICY_FLAG_PASS_TO_USER.

D/WindowManager(1943): isFactoryConfigExist retval = false

V/WindowManager(1943): it's key 186 and down = true

D/WindowManager(1943): keycode is 186 , and POWER is 26

D/WindowManager(1943): mBootFastRuning = false shutdhownPending = false

D/InputManager-JNI(1943): handleInterceptActions: POLICY_FLAG_PASS_TO_USER.

D/WindowManager(1943): isFactoryConfigExist retval = false

V/WindowManager(1943): it's key 186 and down = false

D/WindowManager(1943): shortcut path is app--split--com.google.android.youtube--split--com.google.android.youtube.app.honeycomb.Shell$HomeActivity
W/ContextImpl(1943): Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: ....

---

Any ideas how I can listen this shortcut key press??

Comment: sorry, image of shortcuts keys on http://www.imageupload.co.uk/image/56dN

Comment: If help I can access to full firmware, apk installed, system, etc... where I can look for?

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: hello do you listening in background or in activity ?